# How to do an INNER JOIN query?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join

I have this query:

```
SELECT o.Date, 
  CONCAT (c.FirstName, '',  c.LastName), 
  c.StreetAddress, 
  c.Apt, 
  c.City, 
  c.State, 
  c.ZipCode, 
  c.HomePhone, 
  c.MobilePhone, 
  c.OtherPhone, 
  i.Quantity, 
  d.DonutName, 
  d.Description, 
  d.UnitPrice, 
  o.Notes,
FROM Customer AS c, 
  DonutOrder AS o, 
  OrderLineItem AS i, 
  Donut AS d
INNER JOIN DonutOrder AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Donut AS d ON o.DonutOrderID = i.DonutOrderID
INNER JOIN OrderLineItem AS i ON d.DonutID = i.DonutID 
;
```

I receive this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM Customer AS c, DonutOrder AS o, OrderLineItem AS i, Donut AS d INN' at line 16.

What is wrong?

Here is the link to my SQL Fiddle page: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2842/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues:

- The error is about the trailing comma in the `select` list: the last field should not be followed by a comma
- The `from` clause should not mention a table twice unless you intend so. But in this case you *only* want to use `inner join`, not the comma separated list.
- The join conditions of the last two joined tables should be moved to the other join (swapped)
- The first field in the `select` list does not exist. You probably intended `o.OrderDate`
- In your fiddle there is no data in the `OrderLineItem` table so your query will not return any rows, even if corrected.

Here is the corrected version:

```
SELECT o.OrderDate, 
  CONCAT (c.FirstName, '',  c.LastName), 
  c.StreetAddress, 
  c.Apt, 
  c.City, 
  c.State, 
  c.ZipCode, 
  c.HomePhone, 
  c.MobilePhone, 
  c.OtherPhone, 
  i.Quantity, 
  d.DonutName, 
  d.Description, 
  d.UnitPrice, 
  o.Notes
FROM Customer AS c
INNER JOIN DonutOrder AS o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
INNER JOIN OrderLineItem AS i ON o.DonutOrderID = i.DonutOrderID
INNER JOIN Donut AS d ON d.DonutID = i.DonutID 
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2842/15

Comment: Yes I did mean OrderDate!  Thank you for noticing the extra comma at the end of my Select.  I didn't even think of the no data in my OrderLineItem table.  So that is not necessary in the query then?

Comment: Well, that depends what you want in your output. As you have it now, you need data in the `OrderLineItem` table, because you select the quantity from it. It all depends on what you want to output in case there is no data there. Maybe you want to perform an outer join... For you to decide.

Comment: I removed the OrderLineItem and all the statements with it then added the DonutID and DonutOrderID in my Select statment and Now I am getting the error: Unknown column 'c.CustomerID' in 'on clause'

Comment: I only had to add data into the 3 tables.

Comment: Then answer this question: why is there a 4th table, and do you need to show a quantity in your results? More importantly, you cannot link a customer with a donut in any way if you do not have the order line item record. Check for yourself in the data... how would you know which customer bought which donut?

Comment: You are correct.  So I need to look into doing an outer join to add the quantity.

Comment: I don't know if that is really useful, because you will then also have to outer join the donut table, as it depends on it. And so you will not have the donut name, description, unit price, ... all of which can *only* be known if you have data in the OrderLineItem table.

Comment: So what you are saying is the easiest way to fix it is to insert data into the table?

Comment: Yes, without it you'll not have significant output.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  With the holiday weekend the Course Mentor was not available.  I was able to get it to work by inserting data into my OrderLineItem table.